# SAS simulation not giving an output, trying to understand

Tags: macros, sas, simulation

just as a disclaimer, this is a very low-tech question, but I was unable to find out what's going on. I have a simulation in SAS and whenever I run it, it gives me the simulation itself in the output. What's going on?

*I cannot disclose the code, but I can tell you it is supposed to work. However I haven't been able to find someone in person who knows SAS to show me around, as I am new to the software.*

Additional info: I'm using SAS 9.4. What happens is that the output is the exact same code as the simulation. It doesn't give me any warnings or errors or anything that enables me to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Which SAS product is running the simulation?  How are you looking at the output?  There is not enough information in this question to help.

Comment: What do you mean by giving you the simulation?  Does it just display the CODE that you ran?  Or do you mean that your simulation was too perfect such that when you looked for mean and std your answer exactly matched  the values used for the simulation?  How did you interject randomness into your simulation?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I will edit the OP to reflect this.

Comment: Does your code start with the word %macro somewhere?

Comment: Also check your work library for a data set, maybe you don't have output results but a data set.

Comment: This simulation has ton of macros and mend functions. From what I can gather, the macros call on other macros too. I have a separate data set, but it doesn't seem to want me to import it or anything. The thing that really befuddles me is the lack of any warnings or notes.

Comment: You may just be compiling the code, not actually running it, if its macro. There's also an option to turn off notes (option nonotes). Without anything we can't really help you though. Good luck.

Comment: That's OK, thanks for all the help regardless. I cannot share the code as it's proprietary, but I wanted to get a little guidance. I understand this is about as much as I can get without actually pasting the code (and getting in *massive* trouble).